# What's wrong with my Cordova project's config.xml?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I have successfully deployed the app in the playstore but have been struggling to submit to appstore for the past week. I am getting this on itunes connect:

[image]

So I suppose the problem is with the icon since it is not probably reading the icons, even though the directory is correct.

My config.xml

```
https://pastebin . com/RkheSXRD
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.app.app" version="1.0.5" versionCode="105"          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>App</name>
<description>
    Random App
</description>
<author email="email@gmail.com" href="http://cordova.io">
    WEBSITE.COM
</author>
<icon src="icon.png" />
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="1.5.3" />
<gap:plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin source="git" spec="https://github.com/rodrigo-martinezd/cordova-dialog-gps.git" />
<gap:plugin source="git" spec="https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova.git" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" source="npm">
    <param name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="xxxxxxx" />
    <param name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="xxxxxx" />
</gap:plugin>
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<access origin="*" />
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
<gap:config-file parent="/manifest" platform="android">
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </application>
</gap:config-file>

<icon src="www\Android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png" platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="www\Android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png" platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="www\Android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png" platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="www\Android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png" platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" />
<icon src="www\Android\res\drawable-xxhdpi\icon.png" platform="android" qualifier="xxhdpi" />

<splash src="www\Android\res\drawable-ldpi\screen.png" platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" />
<splash src="www\Android\res\drawable-mdpi\screen.png" platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" />
<splash src="www\Android\res\drawable-hdpi\screen.png" platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" />
<splash src="www\Android\res\drawable-xhdpi\screen.png" platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" />
<splash src="www\Android\res\drawable-xxhdpi\screen.png" platform="android" qualifier="port-xxhdpi" />


<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-60.png" platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-76@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-167.png" platform="ios" width="167" height="167" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-small.png" platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-small@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-small@3x.png" platform="ios" width="87" height="87" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-40.png" platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-40@2x.png" platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />

<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon.png" platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon@2x.png" platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-72.png" platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-72@2x.png" platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-small.png" platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-small@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-50.png" platform="ios" width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="www\iOS\res\icons\Icon-50@2x.png" platform="ios" width="100" height="100" />

<splash src="www\iOS\res\splash\Default.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<splash src="www\iOS\res\splash\Default@2x.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
<splash src="www\iOS\res\splash\Default-568h@2x.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
<splash src="www\iOS\res\splash\screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
<splash src="www\iOS\res\splash\screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
<splash src="www\iOS\res\splash\screen-ipad-portrait.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
<splash src="www\iOS\res\splash\screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />

<engine name="android" spec="~6.2.3" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^1.10.5">
    <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="xxxxx" />
</plugin>
```

Comment: Just drop a 1024 x 1024 icon over the cordova icon in the app store.

Answer (score 0):

The following entries should be available in your config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />     
    <!-- images are determined by width and height. The following are supported -->
    <splash src="www/images/ios_splash_icons/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="www/images/ios_splash_icons/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="www/images/ios_splash_icons/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="www/images/ios_splash_icons/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="www/images/ios_splash_icons/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="www/images/ios_splash_icons/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="www/images/ios_splash_icons/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="www/images/ios_splash_icons/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="www/images/ios_splash_icons/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="www/images/ios_splash_icons/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <!-- logo icons -->
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="www/images/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons//icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="www/images/ios_logo_icons/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
</platform> 
<icon src="www/images/icon.png" />
```

Comment: I do have included all those images and splashes though in the config.xml that I have specified. I am compiling through phonegap and on open the ipa as zip I see that the icons and splash on the root directory are of the default cordova image

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the **config.xml** refers to icon and splash images inside the **www** directory. It would probably be better to have the images in a separate directory at the same level as www (e.g. ***res/icons/ios/..***) since having them inside the www directory means that all the images will be packaged twice into the app, and therefore make the app size unnecessarily large.

- Do you have a default icon in the root (one step above www) of your
  project as defined in the `<icon src="icon.png" />` tag?
- Go through each image file and ensure that all of them have the exact
  same dimensions (width and height) as specified in the **config.xml**. If not, they may be ignored which could explain your issue.

Another thing:
You can unpack the IPA file and check the contents instead of having to upload it to iTunes to check if the icons are correctly replacing the default icons. Just rename the app file with .zip as the extension (make a copy if you intend to later upload the same file to iTunes), unpack it and navigate down into the app directory where the icons reside.

Update:

Since no icons and splash screens are replaced by PhoneGap build it sound like there is something wrong with the path to each one in the config.xml. The path for each file is relative to the location of the config.xml file itself, according to the official [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/), and it is also recommended to put the files into a directory in the root of the project other than the www directory. The config.xml should reside in the top level of the project: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/getting-started/app-project-structure/

I would also use the recommended way of specifying icons and splash screens for each platform in the config.xml, it is easier to read and modify:

```
<platform name="ios">
  <icon src="icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
  ...
</platform>
```

Instead of:

```
<icon src="icon-60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />
...
```

Same goes for platform android.

Build logs:
PhoneGap produces a build log for each build. It should contain useful information about this issue. Search for lines that have texts similar to these:

PhoneGap build indicates that an icon file has the wrong dimensions/size:

> warning: AppIcon.appiconset/icon-76@2x.png is 180x180 but should be
>   152x152.

PhoneGap build indicates that an icon file wasn't found:

> A 60x60@2x app icon is required for iPhone apps targeting iOS 7.0 and
>   later

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer,
However 1) I tried moving it to a separate directory eg.(res/icons) doesnt help my problem though :(
2)Yeah including the icon.png is the first thing to do :P
3)I think thats where the problem is, I opened it as archive and in the root folder it is showing like this
http://imgur.com/a/qommu
Thanks for helping me identify the problem. It isnt recognising the icons I have uploaded, it is adding the default cordova icons and splash. How do i fix it? Is there a problem in config.xml? Thanks P.S. i am compiling using phonegap

Comment: From the screenshot of the unzipped app file, it certainly looks like all your images are ignored. And the dimensions of your images are correct, i.e. they correspond to the ones given in the config.xml? Also, if you check the www dir in the unzipped ipa file, do your images reside within the iOS\res\icons\ file there?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more stuff related to PhoneGap build. One thing that would be useful in this case is to know what the directory structure of your project looks like. Could you please update the questions with this information?

Comment: Here is the directory structure http://txt.do/dk71o I have been working on this problem for the last week and have already tried the things you have suggested besides other things. The android build is fine but on compiling ios through build.phonegap.com the icons are replaced. You must have noticed that in my directory structure there are two "res" folders, it is because I saw somewhere that path is relative to www. So i uploaded images to both locations, since size is not an important issue right now. The image resolution are all correct, i have checked like 10+ times.

Comment: And yes the icons reside within the iOS\res\icons\ folder because the www folder is untouched. Here is my ipa directory structure http://txt.do/dk71f Really thanks for the help that you are providing.

Comment: Have you checked the build log as I mentioned above? It would be helpful to see what the PhoneGap build system says about the splash screens and icons.